# Determine the reason of high concurrency

Tags: concurrency, oracle12c

I'm using Oracle-12C. Like locking in Oracle, we can determine it by v$session, and based on sql_id we can get the text also plan.

My problem is how can determine which statement is the reason lead to high concurrency or any reason else ?

Many thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for `select blocking_session, gv$session.* from gv$session where blocking_session is not null;`?

Comment: No, that just show me the statement is blocking, not the reason lead to high concurrency @JonHeller